# reCaptcha Gem | ERROR: Invalid domain for site key

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, recaptcha

Am trying to use the reCaptcha gem for a site and have followed all the suggestions to build the captcha.

The reCaptcha shows on localhost but when deployed to production I only get "ERROR: Invalid domain for site key"

Not sure what do I need to do here. Site deployed at http://bit.ly/1EajuIk.

The version of the Gem that i am using is recaptcha (0.3.6) and the config file is:

```
Recaptcha.configure do |config|
  config.public_key = '6Lc6BAAAAAAAAChqRbQZcn_yyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy'
  config.private_key = '6Lc6BAAAAAAAAKN3DRm6VA_xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
  # Uncomment the following line if you are using a proxy server:
  # config.proxy = 'http://myproxy.com.au:8080'
  # Uncomment if you want to use the newer version of the API,
  # only works for versions >= 0.3.7:
  # config.api_version = 'v2'
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue seems to be because of an error in my code itself.

We had the incorrect value hard coded in the view where the captcha was being called. And it was not using the config values thus resulting in the error.